# Is it known whether a homeomorphism close to the identity of a compact manifold with nonzero Euler characteristic necessarily has a fixed point?

Tags: manifolds, fixed-point-theorems, euler-characteristics, homeomorphism

I recently saw in Kirby's list of open problems that it isn't known if two commuting homeomorphisms of a compact manifold close to the identity necessarily share a common fixed point, when the manifold has nonvanishing Euler characteristic. Since every homeomorphism commutes with the identity, I was wondering if the simpler problem in the title was solved. I can't seem to find any references where this is done. Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't this follow from the Lefschetz trace formula? Because the map is homotopic to the identity, its trace on homology is the Euler characteristic. Because it's nonzero, there must be at least one fixed point.

Comment: That is correct! Thank you and I'm sorry for the silly question.